# why Beta(1,1) is an improper prior

Tags: bayesian, prior

While I am looking for the sun-rise problem, in part of prior selection they said that ...

in a section of `Beta distribution` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Rule_of_succession

> Jaynes[53] questions (for the uniform prior Beta(1,1)) the use of these formulas for the cases s = 0 or s = n because the integrals do not converge (Beta(1,1) is an improper prior for s = 0 or s = n).

in proof of `rule of succession` which is using Beta(1,1) as its prior https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession

> This improper prior is 1/(p(1 − p)) for 0 ≤ p ≤ 1 and 0 otherwise.[5]

Where the p is an unknown parameter for the probability of success.
Though I don't know where 1/(p(1 − p)) comes from.

---

`Beta(1,1)` is  `Uniform(0,1)` which is proper prior.
Apparently, it is integrated into one, thus a proper prior.

**Question**: why prior Beta(1,1) in proof for the rule of succession is improper?

Comment: +1.  It looks like Wikipedia is confused.  The "integrals" to which it refers must be the three in the preceding paragraph, but only the one with the Beta$(0,0)$ prior fails to converge for $s=0$ or $s=n.$ It's possible Jaynes was using a different parameterization, one in which the equivalent of Beta$(1,1)$ is improper, so it would be nice to find the relevant passage in Jaynes (which Wikipedia does not cite specifically).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Wikipedia passage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Rule_of_succession)

> Jaynes [[53]](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheory.pdf) questions (for the uniform prior Beta(1,1)) the use of
>   these formulas for the cases $s = 0$ or $s = n$ because the integrals do
>   not converge (Beta(1,1) is an improper prior for $s = 0$ or $s = n$). In
>   practice, the conditions $0<s<n$ necessary for a mode to exist between
>   both ends for the Bayes prior are usually met, and therefore the Bayes
>   prior (as long as $0 < s < n$) results in a posterior mode located
>   between both ends of the domain.

is clearly a typo as the rest of the section

> **Haldane's prior probability (Beta(0,0))**
>
> The Beta(0,0) distribution was proposed by J.B.S. Haldane,[64] who
>   suggested that the prior probability representing complete uncertainty
>   should be proportional to $p^{−1}(1−p)^{−1}$ (...)

calls the Bayes-Laplace prior a Beta(1,1) distribution, Haldane's prior a Beta(0,0) [improper] distribution, and Jeffrey's middle ground a Beta(1/2,1/2) distribution.

Ànother sentence that seems to be wrong is

> According to Jaynes [[53]](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheory.pdf) the main problem with the rule of succession
>   is that it is not valid when $s=0$ or $s=n$ (see rule of succession,
>   for an analysis of its validity).

since Jeffreys' prior, which is supported by [Jaynes](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheory.pdf), has no issue when $s=0$ or $s=n$.